# Junit Parallel Execution with common method

Tags: junit

I am having 6 Junit classes and class have more than one test cases. Can anyone please help me to acheive parallel execution of all test cases at a time only from all classes.

Comment: Hello, please share with us what you already tried

Comment: Hi Marvin Fischer.  You need my implementation?. Actually I am looking for solution which is not yet implemented.